What does Buddhism say about attention?
I read somewhere that:

Attention is a product of/maintained by volition/intention (which is sankhara aggregate).

I am puzzled by this as the following examples illustrate:

I am driving back from a party. I maybe drunk but is 100% focused on the road. Despite this, I find myself driving into a road divider.
I am really interested in heavenly beings. I tried to read up, research and find any materials on this subject. After years and decades of studying, I still do not find any devas around me.
I am studying for an important test tomorrow. I am aware of the test’s importance and trying hard to attend to my study but my mind keeps drifting to the Netflix show on TV.

So, what is attention and how does it work?

Re. the first example, I can intend to lift a table and succeed, or intend to lift a car and fail -- intention isn't enough, maybe strength or skill or similar ability is needed also (which you don't have if you're driving impaired). And that (impairment) like the third example too, I can intend to lift a table but if you pull the mat/rug/carpet from under my feet then I can't, it takes stability and non-interference. Sorry this isn't an answer about what Buddhism says but I don't understand how the question is difficult to understand.

I refer to actions that with the appropriate attention/intention we could normally accomplish. But appropriate intention/attention alone is insufficient in all of the examples above. Are there other co-arising factors that influence attention? To answer that maybe we need to understand what attention is dependant on, I think.

I’m voting to close this question because the behaviour in the question is not Buddhist. This question does not appear to be about Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice, within the scope defined in the help center. The questions gives the impression of normalization getting drunk, driving drunk and that the seeking of angels in a Buddhist practice.

Attention is focused awareness. It's the connection between the simple awareness of Buddha-nature and the active world of 'doing'.
For most of us, attention is constantly moving from one focus to another focus to another. Even when we concentrate on a particular task, our attention is moving through various aspects or steps of the task. Attention rarely rests. Buddhist practices cultivate attention so that it can remain stable and steady, fixed on a particular focus or calmly diffused. Stabilizing attention is merely another way of thinking about quieting thoughts.
To address the specific scenarios…

Driving is an activity that requires us to shift attention rapidly according to changing conditions. Intoxicants slow the movement of attention (which is why it's enjoyable), meaning we might fixate on inconsequential happenings and miss consequential ones. One can meditate while driving — maintaining a calm, diffuse awareness that is sensitive to change — but alcohol reduces that sensitivity to context. We drive into a divider because our attention is caught by a road-sign or nearby car and we miss the slight veer of the wheel that sends us off the road.
Studying is the most intense form of focussed work. Our minds become active as our attention flits between reading this, analyzing that, organizing those ideas. But focussed work implies that attention does not stray outside the confines of that work. A deva (should such a thing exist) could be sitting on your head watching you study, and you would not notice.
As mentioned above, studying is the most intense form of focussed work, implying that attention should not stray outside the confines of work. But that takes discipline, a particular type of attention that self-monitors our impulses, keeping our naturally fluid attention from straying. Discipline is an acquired skill, and takes a certain amount of effort. Some people haven't yet developed the skill, and even among those who have, exhaustion and stress can sap the energy needed to maintain self-attention, so that our minds retreat to the more natural state of unconstrained movement of attention.

Notice that early-stage Buddhist practices tend to focus on self-monitoring focused attention — watching thoughts and emotions raise and fall, fixating on visual points, body-scanning, etc. — while later-stage practices tend to release those and reach for openness, emptiness, or etc. The first are meant to develop the discipline needed to keep attention from wandering, the later meant to hone that disciplined attention so that it is more subtle and expansive.

+1 attention does not stray outside the confines of that work. So it seems attention is dependant on awareness which is in turn a part of consciousness. It is therefore constrained by our awareness/consciousness. Regardless of our intention e.g. to see devas, it cannot go beyond the confines.

The Buddha spoke of abandoning the effluents by seeing (MN 2). He instructed to not attend to things unfit for attention and to attend to things fit for attention.
Attention should be placed for preventing and abandoning sensuality, becoming, and ignorance, it seems. Rather than questioning ourselves about to be, we should question ourselves about dukkha. This is attention in the Buddha's teachings, if you agree.

Attending to the appropriate things is indeed a part of the instructions. But there is more to it as well; a relationship between attention and awareness that @TedWrigley also alluded to. I think it is the key to an awareness of the deathless and this, I believe, needs to be uncovered in the second stage of the practice that was mentioned in his answer.


I am puzzled by this...

SN 46.55 says: when a man dwells with his heart possessed and overwhelmed by ill-will... doubt (lack of faith)... even sacred words he has long studied are not clear to him, not to mention those he has not studied.
About the causes of the befuddled puzzlement in SN 46.55, SN 46.2 says about attention:

And what, bhikkhus, is the nutriment for the arising of unarisen ill
will and for the increase and expansion of arisen ill will? There is,
bhikkhus, the sign of the repulsive: frequently giving careless
attention to it is the nutriment for the arising of unarisen ill will
and for the increase and expansion of arisen ill will
And what, bhikkhus, is the nutriment for the arising of unarisen doubt (lack of faith) and for the increase and expansion of arisen doubt? There are, bhikkhus, things that are the basis for doubt: frequently giving careless attention to them is the nutriment for the arising of unarisen doubt and for the increase and expansion of arisen doubt.




I am driving back from a party. I maybe drunk but is 100% focused on the road. Despite this, I find myself driving into a road divider.

DN 31 says:

(a) "There are, young householder, these six evil consequences in
indulging in intoxicants which cause infatuation and heedlessness:
(i) loss of wealth,
(ii) increase of quarrels,
(iii) susceptibility to disease,
(iv) earning an evil reputation,
(v) shameless exposure of body,
(vi) weakening of intellect.
(b) "There are, young householder, these six evil consequences in
sauntering in streets at unseemly hours:
(i) he himself is unprotected and unguarded,
(ii) his wife and children are unprotected and unguarded,
(iii) his property is unprotected and unguarded,
(iv) he is suspected of evil deeds,
(v) he is subject to false rumours,
(vi) he meets with many troubles.
(c) "There are, young householder, these six evil consequences in frequenting theatrical shows. He is ever thinking:
(i) where is there dancing?
(ii) where is there singing?
(iii) where is there music?
(iv) where is there recitation?
(v) where is there playing with cymbals?
(vi) where is there pot-blowing?
(e) "There are, young householder, these six evil consequences in
associating with evil companions, namely: any gambler, any libertine,
any drunkard, any swindler, any cheat, any rowdy is his friend and
companion.

In conclusion, the puzzled questioner believes they are 100% focused on the road but obviously they are not. Its similar to the drunk approaching the most attractive lady at the party and believing somehow this attractive lady will find the drunk attractive. The driver was not actually 100% focused, just as the attractive lady found the drunk repulsive, because the sankhara aggregate of the drunk & driver was under the influence of alcohol and, deludedly believed they could focus when they actually could not. This is why drunk drivers are often imprisoned to protect the public safety. They believe they are 100% focused when they are not; similar to when internet bloggers often believe they understand Buddhism when they actually do not.

I am really interested in heavenly beings. I tried to read up, research and find any materials on this subject. After years and decades of studying, I still do not find any devas around me.

Heavenly beings are generally 'samsaric gods', i.e., immersed in self-view. They believe in 'selves' such as 'Brahma' or 'Jesus'. There is a sutta somewhere where the Bodhisatta started developing the divine eye and hearing the conversations of devas. The Bodhisatta quickly developed dispassion towards these devas. Later, the Bodhisatta would fully realise anicca, dukkha & anatta and thus make void the devas. In other words, devas are mere phenomena; mere elements. They offer no benefit, unless you need some worldly favours. Deva seekers should probably convert to Christianity. The ultimate goal of Buddhism is to realise there are no real "beings"; that "a being" is merely a "view" (SN 5.10) & "strong clinging" (SN 23.2). In Buddhism, the mental concocting of concepts of various types of "beings" is called "jati/birth" (refer to SN 12.2). To the contrary, the attainment of the Buddhist goal is called the "ending of birth" (khīṇā jāti). "Birth" does not mean "physical birth", "rebirth" or "reincarnation". Those so-called Buddhists who believe "birth" refers to reincarnation simply have not applied proper attention (yoniso manasikara) to the Buddha's teachings, as instructed in AN 10.61, which says:

Not associating with good persons, becoming full, fills up not hearing
the good Dhamma. Not hearing the good Dhamma, becoming full, fills up
lack of faith. Lack of faith, becoming full, fills up careless
attention. Careless attention, becoming full, fills up lack of
mindfulness and clear comprehension. Lack of mindfulness and clear
comprehension, becoming full, fills up non-restraint of the sense
faculties. Non-restraint of the sense faculties, becoming full, fills
up the three kinds of misconduct. The three kinds of misconduct,
becoming full, fill up the five hindrances. The five hindrances,
becoming full, fill up ignorance. Thus there is nutriment for
ignorance, and in this way it becomes full.
AN 10.61



I am studying for an important test tomorrow. I am aware of the test’s importance and trying hard to attend to my study but my mind keeps drifting to the Netflix show on TV.

This excellent example shows how attention is a product of/maintained by volition/intention (which is sankhara aggregate). It is the sensual desire of the sankhara aggregate causing the attention of the mind to drift to a Netflix show. The right intention to study is sankhara aggregate. The wrong intention to watch a Netflix show is also sankhara aggregate. While giving attention to an object obviously also includes the volitional directing of vinnana (consciousness) aggregate; attention refers to directing the mind towards a specific desired intended purpose. That "desired intended purpose" & "directing" is sankhara aggregate.
The word 'attention' in Pali is 'manasikara'. Any words with the root of 'mano' or 'manas' are related to intention & thought (sankhara aggregate) rather than to consciousness (vinnana).

I find no relevancy in most part of the answer and was tempted to downvote if not for the last bit of saving grace from While giving attention to an object obviously also includes... onwards. It would have been better if the answer expanded on why attention in Pali is directly linked to intention and thought even though consciousness has a significant impact on attention.

@Desmon, Venerable Dhamma Dhatu has been quite kind and generous and thorough with references and explanations. Are you perhaps requiring quite a lot for such a subtle topic? Normally StackExchange deals with concrete questions with simple answers such as "what is the syntax for the IF statement".  For subtler questions, references are best, and this is a really subtle issue.

@OyaMist Is it unconventional to use "Venerable" to refer to someone who is not a monk? More importantly, if the question is, "what (factors or conditions) is attention is dependant on?", then mightn't that be answerable with a simple list (of factors or conditions)?

@OyaMist as pointed out the answer is mostly off topic. My examples were to support the question and to give a context. It is weird that >1000 words were spent to address the context and the examples with only 66 words to answer the question proper.

@ChrisW, OH. Apologies for that. I had assumed that the Pali name was given as part of ordination and assumed the honorific. Thank you for the clarification. I will refrain from assuming and drop the honorific henceforth. Regarding your question on factors on conditions, I hesitate to assume that the OP definition of "attention" matches a particular translator's use of that word. Unfortunately, the words "attention" and "consciousness" are not exact and vary in interpretation (witness OP use of attention while DUI).

@Desmon, when a kind person feeds me too much food, I simply take what I need and thank the host. To do otherwise would simply be rude and unappreciated. If you are a monk on alms round, is it proper to complain about too much food?

@OyaMist on behalf of DD, I would like to thank you for standing up for him, thanks! ;-P
